# how to remove and a UnionClass in jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

Currently I am using Jena to work around ontology file, but could not find a way to remove and change a UnionClass.
Could anyone point out how to do this using Jena?
the code for create a UnionClass:

```
RDFNode[] elems = new RDFNode[] {(RDFNode)a,(RDFNode)b};//a&b are 2 clas
UnionClass res=model.createUnionClass(null,model.createList((com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode[])elems));
```

and the API for get a union class:

```
UnionClass res=model.getUnionClass(uriForUnionClass);
```

but how to change res? For example, how to add a class c into this UnionClass?How to remove (RDFNode)a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UnionClass](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/UnionClass.html) is a type of [BooleanClassDescription](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/BooleanClassDescription.html), which simply means classes which are made from other classes by boolean operations (and, or, not).

If you read that documentation you'll find:

```
// Add c to the union
res.addOperand(c);

// Remove a from the union
res.removeOperand(a);
```